# Why is Firebase not signing me out?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

**The problem**

So I am trying to create a flutter app with Firebase and I am following this tutorial series: 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC

and I am on this video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3sY3RWciNw&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC&index=10

whenever I run my code and click the sign out button this appears in the debug console:

```
D/FirebaseAuth( 6371): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event. 
D/FirebaseAuth( 6371): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
```

and I am not sent to the sign in screen as I should.

This is the code for the page where you sign out:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_planner/services/auth.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsPageState createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,

        elevation: 10.0,

        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            iconSize: 35.0,
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back
            ),
          )
        ],

        leading: Icon(
          Icons.settings,
          size: 35.0,
        ),

        title: Text(
          "Settings",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontFamily: "Nunito",
          ),
        ),

      ),

      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Column(
            children: [

              MaterialButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 20.0),
                splashColor: Colors.indigoAccent[700],
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _auth.signOut();
                },
                color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                child: Text(
                  "Sign out",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25.0
                  ),
                ),
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

and these are the other files that the code uses:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:my_planner/models/user.dart';

class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //create user object based on firebase user
  MyUser _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? MyUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream <MyUser> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
      .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  // sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
  
  // sign in with email and password
  
  // register with email and password
  
  // sign out
  Future signOut() async {

    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }

  }

}
```

and

```
class MyUser {

  final String uid;

  MyUser({this.uid});

}
```

any help would be appreiciated.

Comment: Firebase auth is singing you out, this is your app who does not know about this. two ways - implement listener on authentication status or just for the beginning navigate to login page on signout success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This thread is closed**

So this 'error' was caused by the fact that I had a settings page which has the sign out button. This settings page was accessed through the home page. So, when the sign out was called, the stream tried to return the authentication page as the root widget, which was not possible as the settings page was stacked on top. This meant it would not take you to the authentication page.

To solve this I just put a `Navigator.pop()` statement in front of calling `signOut()` so that it navigates to the home page and can switch the root widget to the authentication page.